# Filter a datatable using Date Range

Tags: jquery

Ok,

I have a datepicker range, and two radio buttons, that i need to filter my datatable. Basically, what i'm after is as follows:

User selects date from range picker
User then select either Value Date or Message Date radio button
User clicks Filter button, and the datable fileters based on their selections.

My datatable consists of two date columns, which are represented by the radio buttones. so as an example the user input could be.

From 03/04/2012 to 03/04/2011 on the Value Date column.

Any pointers?

Code as it stands:

```
         <article class="module width_full">
        <header><h3>Message Detail</h3></header>
        <div id="radio">



            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
            <label for="to">to</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />

                   <label for="mdValueDate">Value Date</label>
                   <input type="radio" id="mdValueDate" name="radio" />
                   <label for="mdMessageDate">Message Date</label>
                   <input type="radio" id="mdMessageDate" name="radio" />



                    <button id="btnFilterMd">Filter</button>
                    <button id="btnClearFilter">Clear Filter</button>
                   </div>

              <table      id="tblMessageDetail"            class="display">
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date 1</th>
                        <th>Date 2</th>

                    </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Loading....</td>
                    </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot></tfoot>
              </table>   
            <div id="pager" class="tab_container">


      </div>
    </article>
```

and the jquery code:

```
            function renderMsgDetail(result) {
            var dtMsgDetailData = [];
            $.each(result, function () {
                dtMsgDetailData.push([
                    this.Date1,
                    this.Date2

                ]);
            });

            var oTable = $('#tblMessageDetail').dataTable({
                "aaData": dtMsgDetailData,
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "ALL"]],
                'asStripClasses': null,
                "iDisplayLength": 10
            });


            $("#btnFilterMd").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert($('#from').val());
                alert($('#to').val());
            });
```

Comment: could you provide code?

Comment: ANYONE? I need some assistance please

Comment: why don't you do an ajax call so to get the data filtered? Is it imperative to do it clientside?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the datatable plugin (www.datatables.net).

You have a solution you can adapt here:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

I think you would need a column that shows a value for Value date or message date so that you can apply a filter, if not, javascript would not know how to filter.

Look at the line:

```
 oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
```

The second value would be the index of the column where you have the values to be filtered.

Another solution: ajax call to filter data and fill the table.

Comment: hey netadictos, been away from this project for a while so haven't seen your response. I'm back on it now though

I have two date cols in the rendered table. Basically, the datepicker range, needs to either be run against the ValueDate col or the MessageDate col, depending on what radio button is selected.

I'm having trouble working this out